# how to sum two fields

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I'm trying to perform Arithmetic Operators and this is my query ,

```
SELECT

    GLB.BEGIN_BALANCE_DR_BEQ + GLB.BEGIN_BALANCE_CR_BEQ AS ACTIVITY,
    GLB.PERIOD_NET_DR + GLB.PERIOD_NET_CR AS BEG_BALANCE ,
    ACTIVITY + BEG_BALANCE AS END_BALANCE,
    SUM(ACTIVITY) AS TOTAL_ACT,
    SUM(BEG_BALANCE) AS TOTAL_BEG_BALANCE,
    SUM(END_BALANCE) AS TOTAL_END_BALANCE,
```

But it didn't work , Can anyone guide me how can I fix it ?!

Comment: That's just half of the query... How does the rest look?

Comment: Please tag properly.  It's either MySQL or Oracle, can't be both.

Comment: Also that query you posted will definitely not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use alias in the same select level (and you can't use aggregation level and not aggregated  column without a proper group by)  in  yor case

you should use a subquery for a fast use of alias eg:

```
  SELECT 
      SUM(ACTIVITY) AS TOTAL_ACT,
      SUM(BEG_BALANCE) AS TOTAL_BEG_BALANCE,
      SUM(END_BALANCE) AS TOTAL_END_BALANCE
      FROM( 
        SELECT

        GLB.BEGIN_BALANCE_DR_BEQ + GLB.BEGIN_BALANCE_CR_BEQ AS ACTIVITY,
        GLB.PERIOD_NET_DR + GLB.PERIOD_NET_CR AS BEG_BALANCE ,
        ACTIVITY + BEG_BALANCE AS END_BALANCE
        FROM My_TABLE 
      ) T
```

Comment: i don't think `ACTIVITY` and `BEG_BALANCE` can be referenced in the SELECT list of the query where those aliases are assigned. If we want to return `END_BALANCE` from the inline view, we'd need to use an expression that references columns available in the SELECT list. In this case, I don't think we really need to return `END_BALANCE`, we could do `SUM(ACTIVITY+BEG_BALANCE)` in place of `SUM(END_BALANCE)` in the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

It's not valid for aliases assigned in the SELECT list of the query to be referenced elsewhere in the SELECT list or in the WHERE clause of the same query. (MySQL does have extensions which allows a column alias to be referenced in ORDER BY and HAVING.)

If we want to reference an alias in the SELECT list, one option is to make the query into an inline view. And an outer query can reference an alias as a columname. As a simple example...

```
 SELECT c.myalias
      , c.fee
      , c.myalias + c.fee AS grand_tot
   FROM ( SELECT t.somecol + t.othercol  AS `myalias`
               , t.fi + t.fo + t.fum     AS `fee`
            FROM t
        ) c
```

For performance reasons, we would typically avoid doing this, due to the cost of materializing the inline view as a derived table. It would be much more efficient to avoid the inline view, and reference columns that are available, even if we have to repeat expressions.

```
 SELECT t.somecol + t.othercol                       AS `myalias`
      , t.fi + t.fo + t.fum                          AS `fee`
      , t.somecol + t.othercol + t.fi + t.fo + t.fum AS `grand_tot`
   FROM t
```

---

It's not clear what resultset twe are needing to return.

If we want just the totals, I'd avoid an inline view, and just bite the bullet and use expressions that reference columns that are available in the SELECT list. It seems like an odd resultset to return:

```
SELECT SUM( GLB.BEGIN_BALANCE_DR_BEQ 
          + GLB.BEGIN_BALANCE_CR_BEQ
       ) AS TOTAL_ACT
     , SUM( GLB.PERIOD_NET_DR
          + GLB.PERIOD_NET_CR
       ) AS TOTAL_BEG_BALANCE
     , SUM( GLB_GLB.BEGIN_BALANCE_DR_BEQ 
          + GLB.BEGIN_BALANCE_CR_BEQ 
          + GLB.PERIOD_NET_DR
          + GLB.PERIOD_NET_CR
       ) AS TOTAL_END_BALANCE
  FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two types of operations in this query.  The first three lines are single row operations and the last three are multi row operations. As it's written you are asking for value of `GLB.BEGIN_BALANCE_DR_BEQ + GLB.BEGIN_BALANCE_CR_BEQ AS ACTIVITY` for each row, and the sum of `ACTIVITY` across all rows.

If you want the sum of each field across all rows then you have to wrap each call in the `sum(...)` function.  If you want a mix of single and multi row fields then you have to split them into two queries.